# Simple Javascript div Fade-In not working

Tags: javascript, html, fadein

Below is the code that I am currently using to fade in 4 divs with a 2 second interval between each one. I am using this in a BXslider so as the slide slides into view the 4 divs will load. However although it is a very simple piece of coding. It does not fade in any of the divs, they are just there. Can somebody see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

***My Javascript***

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#element1').delay(2000).fadeTo(0, 2000);
$('#element2').delay(4000).fadeTo(0, 2000);
$('#element3').delay(6000).fadeTo(0, 2000);
$('#element4').delay(8000).fadeTo(0, 2000);
});
</script>
```

***My HTML***

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide1.png);"><div>
<div id="element1" style="margin:200px;">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF;">we are the cambridge graphic design company...</h1>
</div>
<div id="apDiv4"></div>
<div id="element2" style="margin:200px;">
  <div id="apDiv3"></div>
  <h2 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF; text-align: right; font-size: 16px;">we design brochures, catalogues, business cards, leaflets, cd covers and much much more. </h2>
</div>
</li> 
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide2.png);"><div>
<div id="div1" style="margin:200px;">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF;">...we are the cambridge website design company...</h1>
</div>
<div id="apDiv4"></div>
<div id="div2" style="margin:200px;">
  <div id="apDiv3"></div>
  <h2 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF; text-align: right; font-size: 16px;">offering bespoke, creative website design for small and large businesses of all types to help increase sales. </h2>
</div></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide3.png);;"><div>
<div id="div1" style="margin:200px;">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF;">...we are the cambridge budget design company...</h1>
</div>
<div id="apDiv4"></div>
<div id="div2" style="margin:200px;">
  <div id="apDiv3"></div>
  <h2 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF; text-align: right; font-size: 16px;">offering budget & templated websites, business rebranding, start up business rebranding and much much more.</h2>
</div></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide4.png);"><div>
<div id="div1" style="margin:200px;">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF;">...we are the cambridge advertising agency...</h1>
</div>
<div id="apDiv4"></div>
<div id="div2" style="margin:200px;">
  <div id="apDiv3"></div>
  <h2 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF; text-align: right; font-size: 16px;">we provide 6 month or 12 month advertising schedules as well as one off adverts for many, many businesses.</h2>
</div></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide5.png);"><div>
<div id="div1" style="margin:200px;">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF;">...we are cambridge copy writers...</h1>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="margin:200px;">
  <h2 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #FFF; text-align: right; font-size: 16px;">whether you have an article, a poem or a novel, we will review, edit or write it for you.</h2>
```

None of the answers so far have helped for some reason :(, I have also just tried this code below but nothing!

```
$(function() {  
$('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 2000).fadeIn(1000);
});
});
```

Comment: Fading uses CSS styling. Did you make sure the divs are hidden by default?

Comment: Viewing that page's source, there are no elements with IDs `element1` to `element4`

Comment: Hi @kei thanks, I do not mean to sound rude but there are... I just looked at them to double check lol :) thanks though

Comment: @koljanep I was hoping that the above code was all I needed and I could achieve the effect just with the Javascript

Comment: Nope, not rude at all! My bad I viewed source on a different tab! (:

Comment: Seems, you have set the fadeTo-parameters wrong. See jquery API documentation:
.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, complete ] )

http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/

Comment: It does look like that those IDs are getting stripped out in the generated HTML most likely because the bxslider code is modifying the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://fiddle.jshell.net/y5p6udau/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#element1').delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
$('#element2').delay(4000).fadeOut(2000);
$('#element3').delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
$('#element4').delay(8000).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

anyway this is a very bad approach , i would use all back function to fire next fadeOut instead.

Comment: Thats great @ProllyGeek but I need a fade in. I had this exact code before haha! Thanks for answering anyway though man

Comment: @DanielNolan in your code yu have used fadeTo 0 , so i thought you want to fade out your item , anyway as i said this will not be a good approach.

Comment: although its a bad approaach could you still show me the fadeIn. Its more to learn than anything else.

Comment: do yoy still need an answer ?

Comment: I give up! I have no idea why such a simple thing has caused so many problems... I did this before about 6 months ago in about 5 minutes haha

Comment: I can help if you still need it :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `fadeTo(duration, opacity)`, but you give the opacity as first argument. And if you want to fade in, your opacity should be 1 (or just use `fadeIn()` ).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="slideshow">
 // wrap everything inside her
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    SlideShow();
})

    function SlideShow() {
        $('#slideshow > div:gt(0)').hide();  
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(2000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: Yes you do.Also create the JS file separate and references within the html/aspx page

Comment: @DanielNolan checkout this example here http://jsfiddle.net/3v3wt9hb/ and this one http://jsfiddle.net/3v3wt9hb/2/ which ever one that will work for you

Comment: I give up! I have no idea why such a simple thing has caused so many problems... I did this before about 6 months ago in about 5 minutes haha